# Failed to generate a native image: GRAALVM_HOME was not set

Tags: graalvm

Failed to generate a native image: GRAALVM_HOME was not set (MacOsx)

I have set the classpath, running the set command gives me,
GRAALVM_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-19.0.0/contents/home. java -version points to OpenJDK GraalVM CE 19.0.0...

I was expecting to successfully build native quarkus images

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this, thanks to Marcus Biel, Quarkus is not ready for Java 11, So I pointed JAVA_HOME to java8, so I set up an alias to enable easy switching between J8 and J11 as it may be required in different projects.